# Why does this regular expression not return the second word

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I have the following regex expression (code below), however I am very confused as to why it does not return 'Banas' since it is a word and is between 2 and 20 characters.

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s[A-Za-z]{2,20}\\s");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(" Derek Banas CA 1234 PA (750)555-1234");

    while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

The output is below. Why is "Banas" not in the output? Thanks.

```
Derek CA PA
```

Comment: Could it be because the space between "Derek" and "Banas" is in the " Derek " group and therefore can't also be in the " Banas " group? Maybe try removing the leading \\s?

Answer (score 6):

Because first match consumed space after `Derek` so `Banas` cant use it at start. Try maybe changing your regex to `"\\b[A-Za-z]{2,20}\\b"`. `\\b` is [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) which will match only places that are

> - before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> - after the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> - between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Answer (score 3):

Because your regular expression has a space at the start and end of it. So when your regular expression finds " Derek ", the next part of your string is "Banas " and your regular expression would only work for " Banas ".

Answer (score 1):

Using `\\b` (as @Pshemo answered) is probably the best answer for your problem.  I wanted to mention another possibility, though: if you use lookahead, you can look for a space (or any other pattern) without consuming it.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s[A-Za-z]{2,20}(?=\\s)");
```

Now the pattern will match if the sequence of letters is followed by a space, but the space won't become part of the match, and it will remain in the string so that it can be matched by the next call to `find()`.  The strings returned by `m.group()` will be `" Derek"`, `" Banas"`, `" CA"`, `" PA"`.